# Blender file size doubles from 160MB to 370MB after saving in 3.3.1

Tags: blend-files

I have a file that already is bloated to 160MB since I have packed all resources when I was on 3.2 and then I was trying to find a way to reduce it in Blender 3.2. When I opened the file in Blender 3.3.1, and tried to do a cleanup with *File > Cleanup* and then saved the file, it suddenly doubled to 370MB in size. That definitely is not normal. How do I reduce it back to 160MB or less?

Comment: did you try to make a new file and just import everything?

Comment: When saving, in upper right of the window there's a gear icon ⚙ - click it and make sure "compressed" is checked.

Comment: hey guys thanks for the response! I did the compressed option and it did bring it down to 220MB thank you! Still wondering where the 220-160=80MB have come from, really odd.

Comment: Did you mark stuff as assets ? It adds some overhead memory which can amont to a lot if you have a lot of objects

Comment: @Gorgious, i didn't mark anything as asset. I just had a 160MB file and decided to press `Ctrl+S` in 3.3.1 from 3.2 and bam it became 360MB XD

Comment: Alright. Another culprit might be "File>External Data>Automatically pack resources" is ticked ON in your 3.3 settings and not 3.2

Comment: @Gorgious I actually have all files packed in 3.2, that is why it was so huge at 160MB. So there was actually nothing else to pack in, unless 3.3.1 decided to pack a duplicate copy of the resources again.